# ClickOnce deployment - unable to install

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce, uninstallation

Unable to install the windows application through ClickOnce deployment.

I have uninstalled my DEV version of the application. But when I am trying to install test version, it is popping up error message "Application with same identity already exists".

I have uninstalled my application through Control Panel. Is there any other way to find whether the application exist in the system.

Comment: was a reference created in the registry?

Answer (score 0):

a quick google came up with the below: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d7d57446-f0b2-4b9e-96b8-966218306ddd/unable-to-install-an-application-because-an-application-with-the-same-identity-is-already-installed?forum=vsto

> According to this link, the workaround is to clear the ClickOnce cache
>   of application manifests before reinstalling. To clear the ClickOnce
>   cache,
>
> 1. Open command prompt by inputting cmd in Run from Start menu.
> 2. Switch to the path which mage.exe is in. In my side, the path is C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin. Input "cd
>      C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin".
> 3. Now input Mage.exe -cc. It will appears a notice: Application cache cleared.